# Is there a way to access response outside of the JsonObjectRequest?

Tags: android, android-volley

Using Volley, I am making a JsonObjectRequest named `jsonRequest`. I want to access the response outside of `jsonRequest` so I can send it to other activities. If I do `val jsonResult = response` and try to access it in `intent.putExtra("response", jsonResult)`, I get a "Unresolved Reference" error. How would I do this? My code is below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val itemsURL = "https://prices.csgotrader.app/latest/prices_v6.json"
        val requestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)

        val jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, itemsURL, null,
            { response ->
                TODO() // JsonResult
            },
            { error ->
                val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Error")
                dialogBuilder.setMessage(error.message)
                dialogBuilder.create().show()
            })
        requestQ.add(jsonRequest)

        main_activity_btnSearch.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("response", jsonResult)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        main_activity_btnPortfolio.setOnClickListener {
            TODO()
        }

        main_activity_btnTrending.setOnClickListener {
            TODO()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three ways:

1. Create class with field like `var json = JsonObject()` and set it when you will get it.
2. Send it like string to another activity and convert it to JsonObject:

   ```
   val answer = JSONObject(string_from_intent)
   ```
3. If you will finally convert this jsonobject to model class you can send via intent parcelable model class to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Practices by google:**

The best to implement your case is by using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).

When your api calls completed you need to update your liveData using

```
liveData.postValue("your response data")
```

From your activity you can observe liveData, with this method you can fetch your api response into activity at runtime.

```
YourApiClass.livedata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
       // Here you can update your UI with the live data coming from api
   }
```

For details check [Android App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide?gclid=Cj0KCQjw5uWGBhCTARIsAL70sLKDuZ-6Tt-slLA53noeKMO-HiBpV1juf-TlunMBDDBO4NH0QYxCtSQaAjcaEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)